# Unable to understand what type the function is returning

Tags: c++, sorting, oop, pointers, stack

I'm trying to sort a stack by using another stack and a temporary variable. In the sort function, when I'm trying yo return the address of the second stack I'm not sure what type it is returning. Because I'm getting two errors:

```
file0.cpp: In function 'int main()':  
file0.cpp:97:23: error: cannot convert 'int*' to 'stack*'
   97 |     arr.ad = sort(one.a);
```

and

```
file0.cpp:46:17: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'int sort(stack*)'
   46 | int sort(stack* obj){
      |          ~~~~~~~^~~
```

So, these are the errors I'm getting. I'm tried many things by changing the sort function to:

```
stack* sort();
 int* sort();
```

None of them are working well. So could anyone please explain what is wrong with the code and correct it? And what are topics I must learn better to not make such mistakes again?

````
#include <iostream>
#define MAX 101
using namespace std;

class stack{

public:
int top = -1, a[MAX];
int address;

void push(int x){
   
   a[++top] = x;
}

void pop(){
   top = top - 1;
}

bool isEmpty(){
   if(top == -1){
       return true;
   }else{
       return false;
   }
}

int Top(){
   return top;
}



void print(stack* arr){    //a function to print the stack just confirmaion
   for(int i = 0; i < top; i++){ //that the stack is sorted
      cout << arr->a[i];
   }
 }


 };




 int sort(stack* obj){  //function to sort the stack



 int n = obj->top;
 int temp = obj->a[n]; //a variable to hold the element
 //if it is greater than the Top stack during sorting

 stack two; //second stack for sorting the elements
 if(two.isEmpty()){    //
    two.push(temp);
 }

  
 while(obj->top != 0){
  
  if((temp > obj->a[obj->top]) & (two.a[two.top] > temp)){
      two.push(temp);
  }else if(two.a[two.top] > obj->a[obj->top]){
      two.push(obj->a[obj->top]);
      obj->pop();
  }else{
      temp = obj->a[obj->top];
      obj->pop();
      obj->push(two.a[two.top]);
      two.pop();
  }

 }


  return two.a; //trying to return
  //address of the second stack that I created

 
  }

int main() {
stack one;
one.push(12); //pushing into the stack
one.push(1);
one.push(19);
one.push(14);
one.push(7);
one.push(79);
one.push(3);

stack* a;
a->address = sort(one.a);
one.print(a->address);
return 0;
} 



    
   

```
````

Answer (score 1):

Well many things wrong here. A pointer to a stack is `stack*`, but `two.a` is not a pointer to a stack it's a pointer to the `a` array inside that stack, that would be `int*`.

But the whole approach is wrong. `stack two` is a local variable inside your `sort` function. Because of this it is destroyed when you exit the `sort` function. So if you were to return a pointer to it, or a pointer to the array inside of it, you will be returning a pointer to something that no longer exists and your program will crash.

The simple way to handle this is to return the stack itself, not a pointer. I've also changed `sort` and `print` so that they use references instead of a pointers.

It seems (like many beginners) you are far too quick to use pointers to solve problems that are better solved in other ways. Pointers are definitely an advanced feature of C++, but are rarely needed in good quality C++ code.

Like this

```
stack sort(stack& obj)
{
    int n = obj.top;
    ...
    stack two;
    ...
    return two;
}

void print(const stack& arr){
    ...
}

int main()
{
    stack one;
    one.push(12);
    ...
    stack a = sort(one);
    print(a);
}
```